# Having trouble with SQL MAX()

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, xmlhttprequest

Here is my code.

```
$sql2 = 'SELECT MAX(ASSIGNMENT_ID) FROM assignments';
$result2= mysqli_query($connection,$sql2);
$row2= $result2->fetch_assoc();
$assignment_id=$row2['assignment_ID'];
```

That is the best I have gotten it after many different iterations. I cannot debug this using the xhr.response because I keep getting"XHR failed loading: POST" console messages despite everything posting fine to my SQL database. Apparently that XHR error causes me not to get back any php messages back at all. This problem as a whole I've been stuck on for several hours- any help I would be very appreciative of.

Comment: Hint 1: log `$row2`. Hint 2: `AS`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$sql2 = 'SELECT MAX(ASSIGNMENT_ID) as assignment_ID  FROM assignments';
```

Than use your key `$row2['assignment_ID']`

Comment: Thanks so much. It is a bit hard to find examples where SQL lines are combined with php to show how you retrieve many of the results.